# How do I export two defaults in react? One of them requires a connect and the other doesnt

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-redux

I am trying to combine the exports for these two functions below. One exports using a connect and the other doesn't.

```
const Topics = ({
  getPosts,
  getMostRecentPosts,
  getMostCommentedPosts,
  getMostLikedPosts,
  searchTopics,
  posts,
}) 
  return (
    
  );
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getPosts,
  getMostRecentPosts,
  getMostCommentedPosts,
  getMostLikedPosts,
  searchTopics,
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Topics);
```

and this function exports using only the default

```
  const CreatePost = ({ createPost }) => {
  let [textOfThePost, setTextOfThePost] = useState("");

  const onChange = (e) => setTextOfThePost(e.target.value);

  const submitData = () => {
    if (textOfThePost !== "" && textOfThePost !== null) {
      createPost(textOfThePost);
    } else {
      alert("Text is empty!");
    }
    setTextOfThePost("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="tips-wrapper">
      <br />
      <form>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          value={textOfThePost}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I combine the two exports?

Comment: you can't export 2 functions and both of them as defaults from a single file .but you could split the functions in two different files and export each as a default

Answer (score 0):

You can't make two separate "export defaults" from the same file.

You can either export it to separate files and export default it separately, or you can export each statement in the file separately and call it with curly braces when calling in the component.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that : )